# in insufficiently-polymorphic why do we need the `bbb: B => B => B`?

Tags: scala, haskell

in [insufficiently-polymorphic](http://degoes.net/articles/insufficiently-polymorphic)

why did the author add the 3rd argument: `bbb: B => B => B` what does it mean from b to b to b, why do we need such a thing?

> Let’s say we take this one step further and introduce even more
>   polymorphism into the code, hiding the fact that the second parameter
>   and return values are lists:

```
foo :: forall a b. List a -> (a -> b) -> (b -> b -> b) -> b -> b
def foo[A, B](as: List[A], b: B, ab: A => B, bbb: B => B => B): B
```

and why is there suddenly a conversion function from a to b: `ab: A => B` we didn't have that in original code, why was it added?

Comment: Well... I have not read the full article but as far as I can understand the author is talking about SemiGroups. Now for any set of `T` the `semigroup's` arrow builders will have type `T => T => T`. `A => B` is a morphism from set of `A's` to set of `B's`. Here the intended function will take a `List` of `A` and a morphism from A to B, then uses the `arrows` to fold the morphed `List` of `B`'s into a `B`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is hinted at later in the post with the further generalised version:

```
foo :: forall f a r. (Foldable f, Semigroup r) => f a -> (a -> r) -> r -> r
```

A semigroup is just a structure which supports a binary append operation e.g.

```
trait Semigroup[T] {
    def append(v1: T, v2: T): T
}
```

So `foo` takes an input list, a function to map each list element to some appropriate semigroup instance (the function `a -> b` and an `append` operation for the semigroup. The final `b` parameter is the initial value to accumulate.

`foo` then simply iterates over the list combining the current accumulator with the value associated with the current list item e.g.

```
def foo[A, B](as: List[A], b: B, ab: A => B, bbb: B => B => B): B = 
    as.foldLeft(b)((acc, e) => bbb(ab(e), acc))
```

Lists form a semigroup where `append` just appends the two lists.

Comment: cool.  `e` is the current element traversed by `foldLeft` `ab(e)` means apply conversion from a to b.  `acc` is just an accumulator varialbe to accumulate the result. and `B => B => B` is a notation to denote we have a function of two inputs (the first two B) and single output the third B.  why is it taking me so long to understand such small code? what can I do so it will take me a snap to understand it right now i have to ponder over it for 5 minutes to get the pieces (I see variables not defined so i need to almost guess what is `e` what is `acc` ...)